# PHP and JQuery Variables in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I was wondering if someone could explain me to the best way to go about this situation.

I have a sidebar that is populated with Li Elements from a foreach loop, that works fine.

Each element has an  link that when clicked triggers a Jquery UI Dialog in which there is a text field to add a note and press Submit or cancel, **this opens fine**, **submits fine.**

I can't figure out how to retrieve say the link  tag's id value and the dialogs 
textarea value to submit them to the DB, so the DB is getting populated with 0's, from within the $.ajax Function, **I'm sure it can be done and I'm sure I could hack it working but I want to know the right way to do it. Below is my attempt.**

The JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var note;
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, 
            buttons:{"Add Note": function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>PropertyAdmin/addNoteToProperty", 
                    data:  {name: '20', value: note}, 
                    success:function(result){
                        alert("added");
                    },
                    error: function(result){
                        alert("fail");

                    },
                    cache : false

                });
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }, 

    });
    $(".clickable").click(function (e) {
        // open and move the dialog
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'position',[e.clientX+100,e.clientY]).dialog("open");
        var element = $(this).find("#prop_note");
        note = element.attr("value"); 
        var myTag = $(this).attr('name');
        return false;
    })
})
</script>
```

The Dialog

```
<div id="dialog" title="Add Note">
        <div>
            <?php $attributes = array('role' => 'form'); echo form_open('PropertyAdmin/addProperty', $attributes); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="prop_note" class="control-label">Note :</label>
                <textarea id="prop_note" class="form-control" rows="3" name="prop_note"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CONTROLLER Function

```
function addNoteToProperty(){
    $id = $this->input->post('name');
    $note = $this->input->post('value');
    $this->load->model('PropertyModel');
    $this->PropertyModel->addNoteToProperty($id,$note);
}
```

The Model

```
function addNoteToProperty($propid, $note){
    $data = array('prop_note'=> $note, 'prop_id' => $propid, 'prop_note_date' => now());
    $this->db->insert('property_notes', $data);
}
```

One of my unparsed Li's

```
<li><a href="#" id="toggle1">Investment Properties</a>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($property as $row){ if($row['type_id'] != 1) { } else{ ?>
        <li style="color: white" class="investmentitems inactive"><a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $row['property_name'] ." ".$row['property_address1']; ?></a><?php echo anchor("FinancialInput/listproperty/".$row['id'],"Edit" ); ?><a class="clickable" href="" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Add Note</a></li>
        <?php }} ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Errors

```
 PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for PropertyAdmin::addNoteToProperty()

Filename: controllers/PropertyAdmin.php

Line Number: 44
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 2 for PropertyAdmin::addNoteToProperty()

Filename: controllers/PropertyAdmin.php

Line Number: 44
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: controllers/PropertyAdmin.php

Line Number: 49
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: note

Filename: controllers/PropertyAdmin.php

Line Number: 49
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'prop_note' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `property_notes` (`prop_note`, `prop_id`, `prop_note_date`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 1396465225)

Filename: E:\wamp\www\oak\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the textarea's value? like what you type in? that can be accomplished with a `$(prop_note).val()` in your AJAX data section

Comment: Sorry yes, I'm trying to get the textarea's value and either the "name" value or "id" value of the <a> tag with the class clickable, So I'm basically wanting the note and id of the property of which to add this note, as variables within the ajax function so I can submit them, Am I making any sense haha? Thanks for the code snippet too, I'll see if it works for text area :)

Comment: another quick thing, the `return false` is not a good idea when trying to prevent the page change, use `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks was wondering about that too, I've added what you suggested and it does indeed get the textarea value now but it's still submitting id=0 and value=0, That is the variables show up in Firebug as set but when the controller uses them to load the notesmodel and submit them they're both set to id=0 and value=0 Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post what the `$this->PropertyModel->addNoteToProperty` is?

Comment: Just have done, I had mixed up the controller and model and then only posted one of them, all correct now though and both there :)

Comment: Okay thanks, try setting the type of request in the AJAX function under the `url,` add this `'type' : 'POST',`

Comment: Just to double check 'type' : 'POST' and NOT type : 'POST' ?

Comment: Still doesn't change anything, I'll update the post with the actual errors but basically it's just saying $id and $note are null in the $this->PropertyModel->addNoteToProperty($id,$note) call.

Comment: Looking at it now, It looks like it's calling the addNoteToProperty twice, once with one variable and again with no variables, Am I reading that correct?

Comment: May be a good idea to change the name so they are not the same

Comment: Right I've got it submitting the variables fine, it was my function having accepted params in it still, the only issue I'm left with is getting the id value of the <a> tag whilst IN my ajax function. For example I could it do in the click function of the A link but I can't get the variable into the Ajax data{ name: <alinkidvaluehere>} scope, Any chance you could post that as an answer?

Comment: I changed it so the scope should be able to pick up the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe getting the name value of the a just involves defining your variable outside of the click

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var note;
var name; //ADDED HERE
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, 
        buttons:{"Add Note": function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>PropertyAdmin/addNoteToProperty", 
                data:  {name: name, value: $(prop_note).val()}, 
                success:function(result){
                    alert("added");
                },
                error: function(result){
                    alert("fail");

                },
                cache : false

            });
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }, 

});
$(".clickable").click(function (e) {
    // open and move the dialog
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'position',[e.clientX+100,e.clientY]).dialog("open");
    name = $(this).attr('name'); //Changing the Value here
    return false;
})
})
</script>
```

There you are defining the variable before the click event and changing it to the ID of the `clickable` link before sending it to the PHP controller in the AJAX request